# JavaFX UI freeze hang

Tags: user-interface, javafx

My JavaFX app's UI freezes after consecutive times of executing webservice calls. Those process calls are asynchronous.

How do I fix this problem? Is there a way to "unfreeze" the UI?

Sorry for the newbie question. But I badly need anyone;'s help

Comment: Is it really asynchronous? Please insert relevant part of your code calling the service. Can you try NetBeans JavaFX Composer Data sources to fetch service? If yes, freezes it too? More information will help.

Comment: Its a mobile application and I'm using JavaME's webservice client since the webservice is SOAP and for some reason, JavaFX's webservice functionality won't accept SOAP-based webservices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you create a thread to execute it? JavaFX is executed on the EDT (event dispatch thread). That is why you experience GUI freeze. Here is what you do

```
import javafx.async.*
public class MyWebService extends RunnableFuture {
   public var webserviceURL:String;
   override run(): Void {
     // your web service
   }
}
public class MyWebServiceTask extends JavaTaskBase {
   override create(): RunnableFuture {
      return MyWebService {
         webserviceURL: "http://...."
      };
   }
}

def webserviceTask: MyWebServiceTask = MyWebServiceTask { }
webserviceTask.start();
```

Comment: My UI is in JavaFX while the webservice client and other classes are in JavaME. To answer your question, a thread was created in Java to execute it. Do I still have to use the code you posted above?

Comment: You thread should implement RunnableFuture in Java. The start it with MyWebServiceTask in FX.

Comment: This seems to be old, the async package seems to be removed in javafx2.